# Where is Composition ‣ Paper and Quality panel of QGIS?

Tags: print-composer, layouts, qgis-print-layouts

A **right-click on panel doesn't bring this up** and **not listed in View/Toolbars or View/Panels** ... have a very specific page size so really need to change from default A4.

[image]

Comment: you need make right-click on page and select page properties

Comment: I have right-clicked and there is no option for a Composition panel, only Atlas; Guides; Item Properties; Items; Layout; UnDo History, but no Composition.

Comment: Under Layout/Variables the page size is listed but I can't change it there either.

Comment: Try right-clicking in the layout, not on the panel.

Comment: Also, could you clarify what version you're running, or include a screenshot what what you do/don't see?

Comment: Thanks Josh ... v3.4.4 that was not obvious and I use this facility often in previous versions. Possible to mention to devs to add a drop-down menu as before?